# io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject: How to get the type of the value for given key?

Tags: json, vert.x

I'm using the following package for JsonObject:
http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html

If I get a JsonObject with key 'fieldName' and I want to get its value, I have to use functions such as 'getString', 'getInteger', 'getArray' etc. I mean that I have to know in advanced the type of the value. What happens if I don't know it?
Is there any generic function of retrieving value from JsonObject without knowing its type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [`getValue(String)`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html#getValue-java.lang.String-).

It returns an [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) then you can test the type and cast accordingly.

---

<sup>**Notes for the comments:** Checking the code on GitHub, looks like the `getField(String)` method is present in the `2.x` branch. Looks like `getValue(String)` is delegated to `getField(String)` method ([see the code](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/2.x/vertx-core/src/main/java/org/vertx/java/core/json/JsonObject.java)). As of August 2017, there's no `getField(String)` in the `master` ([see the code](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.java)).</sup>

Comment: getField() also makes the job

Comment: @CrazySynthax there is no `getField()` in the API linked in the question. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Here it is: http://vertx.io/vertx2/api/java/org/vertx/java/core/json/JsonObject.html

Comment: @ci_ See my answer.